# Not able to get value after Do...While loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

Question: Create a function that takes a positive integer and returns the next bigger number that can be formed by rearranging its digits. For example:

```
12 ==> 21
513 ==> 531
2017 ==> 2071
//nextBigger(num: 12)   // returns 21
//nextBigger(num: 513)  // returns 531
//nextBigger(num: 2017) // returns 2071
```

---

I am trying to compare two Array and get correct array as answer. In do...while loop I am comparing the two array by increment second array by one.

```js
function nextBigger(n){
  let nStrg = n.toString();
  
  let nArr = nStrg.split('');
 
  function compareArr(Ar1,Ar2){
    if(Ar2.length>Ar1.length){
      return false;
    }
    for(let i=0; i<Ar1.length; i++){
      let num = Ar1[i];
      for(let j=0; j<Ar2.length; j++){
        if(Ar2.lastIndexOf(num) !== -1){
          Ar2.splice(Ar2.lastIndexOf(num), 1);
          break;
        }
        else{
          return false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  
  let nextNumArr;
  let m = n;
  
  do{
    let nextNum = m+1
    m=nextNum
    
    let nextNumStrg = nextNum.toString();
    
    nextNumArr = nextNumStrg.split('')
    
    
    console.log(compareArr(nArr, nextNumArr))
  }
  while(compareArr(nArr, nextNumArr) == false)
    
  console.log(nextNumArr)
  
  return parseInt(nextNumArr.join())
}

nextBigger(12);
```

This gives me empty array at the end;

Answer (score 1):

`[2,0,1,7].join()` will give you '2,0,1,7', can use `[2,0,1,7].join('')` and get '2017'

Answer (score 1):

All looks a bit complicated. How about:

```js
const nextLarger = num => {
  const numX = `${num}`.split(``).map(Number).reverse();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numX.length; i += 1) {
    if ( numX[i] > numX[i + 1] ) {
      numX.splice(i, 2, ...[numX[i+1], numX[i]]);
      return +(numX.reverse().join(``));
    }
  }
  
  return num;
};

const test = [...Array(100)].map(v => {
    const someNr = Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 100000);
    const next = nextLarger(someNr);
    return `${someNr} => ${
      next === someNr ? `not possible` : next}`;
  }).join('\n');

document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = test;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

[See also](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextlargernr?file=index.js)

Comment: Will not work for 1234567890

Comment: @Tushar It does 1234567890 => 123456**7980**

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nextbig(number) {
  let nums = []
  number.toString().split('').forEach((num) => {
    nums.push(parseInt(num))
  })
  number = nums
  n = number.length
  for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (number[i] > number[i - 1])
      break;
  }

  if (i == 1 && number[i] <= number[i - 1]) {
    return 'No greater possible'
  }

  let x = number[i - 1];
  let smallest = i;

  for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    if (number[j] > x &&
      number[j] < number[smallest])
      smallest = j;
  }

  let temp = number[smallest];
  number[smallest] = number[i - 1];
  number[i - 1] = temp;

  x = 0

  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++)
    x = x * 10 + number[j];

  number = number.slice(i, number.length + 1);
  number.sort()

  for (let j = 0; j < n - i; j++)
    x = x * 10 + number[j];

  return x

}
console.log(nextbig(12))
console.log(nextbig(513))
console.log(nextbig(2017))
```

Comment: this returns 7210 for the last number when it should be 2071

Comment: the biggest number from `2017` is `7210` and not `2071`

Comment: yeah, 7210 is the _biggest_ number, not the _next_ biggest number. The next number that is larger than `2017` is `2071` (using the digits from the original number)

Comment: That's not the question though, the question is to find the next biggest number. So indeed this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @Keshav It's useful to include explanations with your answer and not just code and/or links. You've rewritten all of the code in the question, but you aren't teaching them anything if you don't tell them what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In `compareArr` you are deleting elements as you find them, which is correct to do, to make sure duplicates actually occur twice etc. However, that also deletes the elements from `nextNumArr` in the calling context, because the array is passed by reference and not by value. You need to do a manual copy of it, for example like this: `compareArr(nArr, [...nextNumArr])`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different approach, first I search for all possible combinations of the given numbers with the permutator function. This function returns an array of possible numbers.

Then I sort this array of combinations and look for the index of the given number in the main function.

Once I have this index I return the position before the given number.

```js
function nextbig(num){
    function permutator(inputArr){
        let result = [];     
        const permute = (arr, m = []) => {
          if (arr.length === 0) {
            result.push(m)
          } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              let curr = arr.slice();
              let next = curr.splice(i, 1);
              permute(curr.slice(), m.concat(next))
           }
         }
       }      
       permute(inputArr)
       return result;
    }


    let arrNums = num.toString().split('')
    let combinations = permutator(arrNums).map(elem => parseInt(elem.join("")))

    combinations.sort((a, b) => {
      return b - a
    })
    let indexOfNum = combinations.findIndex(elem => elem === num) 
    let nextBigIndex = indexOfNum <= 0 ? 0 : indexOfNum - 1 
    return (combinations[nextBigIndex])
}

console.log(nextbig(12))
console.log(nextbig(517))
console.log(nextbig(2017))
```